# gcloud compute no longer available after migration to v2beta2

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

After running: `gcloud components update beta`

It seems I lost compute commands:

`gcloud -h
Usage: gcloud [optional flags] <group | command>
  group may be           auth | beta | components | config | dns | preview |
                         topic
  command may be         docker | help | info | init | version`

How do I get compute back in order to run simple things like: `gcloud compute images list --project google-containers | grep container-vm`?

I followed migration path from: https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/latest/migration-guide

This is my `gcloud -v`:

```
Google Cloud SDK 0.9.67

beta 2015.06.30
bq 2.0.18
bq-nix 2.0.18
core 2015.06.30
core-nix 2015.06.02
gcloud 2015.06.30
gcutil-msg 2015.06.09
gsutil 4.13
gsutil-nix 4.12
preview 2015.06.30
```

Everytime I run the `compute` command, console gets in loop until I kill with ctrl+c:

```
[gcloud _19:33:01 $]]^_^ gcloud compute -h

You do not currently have this command group installed.  Using it 
requires the installation of components: [compute]
WARNING: Component [compute] no longer exists.

All components are up to date.
Restarting gcloud command:
  $ gcloud compute -h

You do not currently have this command group installed.  Using it 
requires the installation of components: [compute]
WARNING: Component [compute] no longer exists.

All components are up to date.
Restarting gcloud command:
  $ gcloud compute -h

^C
```

Is there anything I missed?

cheers
Leo

Comment: nevermind. I reinstalled gcloud: curl https://sdk.cloud.google.com | bash

Comment: any idea why is this happening?

Comment: I have no idea. I think it happened because I had an alpha repository previously added for `gcloud compute target-https-proxies`.

Comment: Leonardo's analysis is correct.  Older "trusted tester" repositories don't play well with recent gcloud releases.  If anyone else hits this, you should be able to fix it without reinstalling by doing the following:

  (i) run ````gcloud components repositories list```` and note the repository uri printed out
  (ii) run ````gcloud components repositories delete <uri>````
  (iii) run ````gcloud componets update````

Answer (score 0):

I had same error after updating my `gcloud` tools. I had to replace the current one by re-installing the `gcloud` kit to make it work.